# Get starting dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible, jinja2, devops

I have a problem with the usage of Jinja templating in Ansible. I have this nested dictionary:

```
 "fruits": {
        "summer": {
            "june": {
                "fruit": {
                  "cherry": "cherry"
                },
                "vars": {}
            },
            "july": {
                "fruit": {
                  "peach": "peach"
                },
                "vars": {}
            },
            "august": {
                "fruit": {
                  "watermelon": "watermelon",
                  "strawberry": "strawberry"
                },
                "vars": {}
            }
     }}
```

and I want to remove the object "peach". I have tried with **pop** method, and It works, but I want to use the filter **rejectattr**

I tried:

```
tasks:
- set_fact:
    test: |
      {%- for x,y in fruits.items() -%}
        {%- for j,k in y.items() -%}
          {{ k.fruit | dict2items | rejectattr ('key', 'eq', 'peach') | items2dict }}
        {%- endfor -%}
      {%- endfor -%}`
```

It gives me the following:

```
 "test": "{
    "cherry": "cherry"}
    {}
    {"watermelon": "watermelon", "strawberry": "strawberry"}"
```

But I want to get the starting structure, less "peach" object.

Any suggestion? Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Ansible isn't a great tool for *modifying* deeply nested data structures (or really for modifying data structures in general). While I'm sure someone is going to drop by with a clever `json_query` filter or something, this is trivial to solve by writing a custom filter plugin. If we put the following in `filter_plugins/badfruit.py`:

```
def filter_badfruit(v, *exclude):
    for months in v.values():
        for data in months.values():
            data["fruit"] = {k: v for k, v in data["fruit"].items() if k not in exclude}

    return v


class FilterModule(object):
    filter_map = {"badfruit": filter_badfruit}

    def filters(self):
        return self.filter_map
```

Then we can write a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    "fruits": {
           "summer": {
               "june": {
                   "fruit": {
                     "cherry": "cherry"
                   },
                   "vars": {}
               },
               "july": {
                   "fruit": {
                     "peach": "peach"
                   },
                   "vars": {}
               },
               "august": {
                   "fruit": {
                     "watermelon": "watermelon",
                     "strawberry": "strawberry"
                   },
                   "vars": {}
               }
        }}
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: >-
          fruits|badfruit('peach')
```

And get this output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "fruits|badfruit('peach')": {
        "summer": {
            "august": {
                "fruit": {
                    "strawberry": "strawberry",
                    "watermelon": "watermelon"
                },
                "vars": {}
            },
            "july": {
                "fruit": {},
                "vars": {}
            },
            "june": {
                "fruit": {
                    "cherry": "cherry"
                },
                "vars": {}
            }
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The filter is written so that we can provide multiple keys to exclude:

```
    - debug:
        var: >-
          fruits|badfruit('peach', 'strawberry')
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"I want to use the filter rejectattr."***

A: The *rejectattr* line from your code can be used as is. Combine the dictionaries

```yaml
  test_str: |
    summer:
    {% for i in fruits.summer|dict2items %}
      {{ i.key }}:
        {{ i.value|combine({'fruit': i.value.fruit|dict2items|rejectattr('key', 'eq', 'peach')|items2dict}) }}
    {% endfor %}
  test: "{{ test_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  test:
    summer:
      august:
        fruit:
          strawberry: strawberry
          watermelon: watermelon
        vars: {}
      july:
        fruit: {}
        vars: {}
      june:
        fruit:
          cherry: cherry
        vars: {}
```

---

Optionally, put the excluded items into a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
  exclude:
    fruit: ['peach']
```

and walk the tree. The variable *test* will expand to the expected result as well

```yaml
  test_str: |
    {% for season,sa in fruits.items() %}
    {{ season }}:
    {% for month,ma in sa.items() %}
      {{ month }}:
    {% for a,b in ma.items() %}
        {{ a }}:
          {
    {% for k,v in b.items() %}
    {% if k not in exclude[a] %}
          {{ k }}: {{ v }},
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
          }
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  test: "{{ test_str|from_yaml }}"
```